# Why does the subwoofer hum when no source is connected?

Tags: power-supply, audio, noise, grounding, speakers

The hum at 60Hz stops as soon as an audio source is connected and came with a 2 pin connector.

I tried to connect any part of the subwoofer with the ground of a socket. The buzzing stops when no device is connected. I can then connect my phone normally with an aux cable and listen to music. When I try to do this with my laptop, a strange beeping sound is emitted.

The problem occurs on all sockets and therefore I suspect that the power supply has a problem. It is important to note that the subwoofer is a few years old. In the pictures you can see the components of the device. Which component could be the source of the problem?

[image: Subwoofer-1]

[image: Subwoofer-2]

Comment: Sounds normal. Your laptop charger is probably to blame. If you connect your laptop without the AC adapter, as in running on batteries, does the bad noise go away?

Comment: Typically, a 50/60Hz or 100/120Hz hum is caused due to a simple AC-DC power supply, but it looks like your subwoofer has a switch-mode psu (2nd pic) and shouldn't have a mains frequency hum, yet it does. its quite odd. Also, what is that beeping sound that you hear when you connect your laptop to the subwoofer?